Investigating ways to temporary authenticate in AWS S3 using federated API access through SAML 2.0
Our project have an application (placed in CNET and running under a process account) that sends files to a S3 bucket every 6 hours and works well, although we need to manually rotate these keys time to time (60~70 days) - we are using IAM Users to authenticate and one IAM Role with only write permissions in our S3.
We are seeking ways to improve manual tasks in our platform and would like to check with you if this is a approved path and feasible to achieve, suggested by AWS: How to Implement a General Solution for Federated API/CLI Access Using SAML 2.0
Is there a way to this process account assume a role in AWS and get authenticated?
# Get the federated credentials from the user
username = ''
password = ''
print('')

# Initiate session handler
session = requests.Session()

# Programmatically get the SAML assertion
# Opens the initial IdP url and follows all of the HTTP302 redirects, and
# gets the resulting login page
formresponse = session.get(idpentryurl, verify=False)
# Capture the idpauthformsubmiturl, which is the final url after all the 302s
idpauthformsubmiturl = formresponse.url

# Parse the response and extract all the necessary values
# in order to build a dictionary of all of the form values the IdP expects
formsoup = BeautifulSoup(formresponse.text, features="html.parser")
payload = {}

for inputtag in formsoup.find_all(re.compile('(INPUT|input)')):
    name = inputtag.get('name','')
    value = inputtag.get('value','')
    if "user" in name.lower():
        #Make an educated guess that this is the right field for the username
        payload[name] = username
    elif "email" in name.lower():
        #Some IdPs also label the username field as 'email'
        payload[name] = username
    elif "pass" in name.lower():
        #Make an educated guess that this is the right field for the password
        payload[name] = password
    else:
        #Simply populate the parameter with the existing value (picks up hidden fields in the login form)
        payload[name] = value

# Debug the parameter payload if needed
# Use with caution since this will print sensitive output to the screen
#print payload

# Some IdPs don't explicitly set a form action, but if one is set we should
# build the idpauthformsubmiturl by combining the scheme and hostname 
# from the entry url with the form action target
# If the action tag doesn't exist, we just stick with the 
# idpauthformsubmiturl above

for inputtag in formsoup.find_all(re.compile('(FORM|form)')):
    action = inputtag.get('action')
    if action:
        parsedurl = urlparse(idpentryurl)
        idpauthformsubmiturl = parsedurl.scheme + "://" + parsedurl.netloc + action

# Performs the submission of the IdP login form with the above post data
response = session.post(
    idpauthformsubmiturl, data=payload, verify=False)

# Debug the response if needed
print (response.text)

# Overwrite and delete the credential variables, just for safety
username = '##############################################'
password = '##############################################'
del username
del password

# Decode the response and extract the SAML assertion
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
assertion = ''

# Look for the SAMLResponse attribute of the input tag (determined by
# analyzing the debug print lines above)
for inputtag in soup.find_all('input'):
    if(inputtag.get('name') == 'SAMLResponse'):
        print(inputtag.get('value'))
        assertion = inputtag.get('value')

# Better error handling is required for production use.
if (assertion == ''):
    #TODO: Insert valid error checking/handling
    print('Response did not contain a valid SAML assertion')
    sys.exit(0)

